# Know the transmission speed between PICAXEs with Radio module

Tags: radio, remote-control, picaxe

I was wondering if I could know the transmission speed between 2 PICAXEs using an Radio Module.

At the moment I tried to send data between 2 PICAXE 40x2 only with the 433MHz Radio Transmitter. The transmission works but its speed is very slow, like 1 package every 5 seconds.

Is it possible to increase this transmission speed?

I also read I should use the NKM2401 Radio Encoder/Decoder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are asking about transmission rates not transition rates.

The transmission speed depends on a variety of factors including (but not limited to)

- the type of interface between PICAXE and module

  - it's clock rate or baud rate etc
- the radio signalling system used by the radio module
- the data encapsulation and protocols used by the module or Picaxe
- the amount of local interference/noise in the radio spectrum used

  - assuming checksums and retransmits are used.

Comment: Ups, you're right. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I have more idea of what might be wrong.